# WPF Binding a textbox to a property of all items in a generic list

Tags: wpf, binding

What I want to do is simple. I have a generic list of objects. Let's say the object class contains a property named Height. What I want to do is bind a textbox's text in the UI with this list and when i change the value in the textbox then all objects in the list update their height value. I am new in WPF, I have studied the MVVM pattern, I can do simple data binding but i can't figure out how to do this :'( Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would have a Property of your ViewModel (let's call it ObjectHeight) which is bound to the text value of the TextBox. When the text property changes (i.e. in the `set` for ObjectHeight), do your validation to check it's a valid value, then iterate over the object list (which I guess you're getting from your Model) setting the Height Property on each.

Comment: Instead of creating a bunch of properties in the viewmodel i could create a class which derives from the object class used in the list and do the work there. Because there are a lot of values to bind to, not just height :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the binding the other way - that is, not use xaml to bind to a single object's Height property, but instead use code-behind to add a binding to every object in the list.

Something like this (untested):

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Text");
binding.source = TheTextBox;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
foreach (var o in myList)
o.setBinding(TheElementType.HeightProperty, binding);
```

Maybe you'll have to create one binding object per target object; and the Object's Height property will probably have to be a DependencyProperty.